# no puedo encontrar el error

Tags: excel, vba

```
"" Sub Combinar()
    Dim shtHoja1 As Worksheet
    Dim strNombre As String
    Dim strApellido As String
    Dim strDNI As String
    Dim strCorreo As String
    Dim objPPT As Object
    Dim objPres As Object
    Dim objSld As Object
    Dim objShp As Object

    'Set shtHoja1 = Worksheets("INSCRIPCIONES")
    Set objPPT = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
    objPPT.Visible = True

    Set objPres = objPPT.presentations.Open("C:\Users\tamar\OneDrive\Escritorio\Banco\CERTIFICADO1.pptx")
    objPres.SaveAs 
   "C:\Users\tamar\OneDrive\Escritorio\Banco\U4\CertificadoDNIApellido.pptx"

    PrimeraFila = 2
 
  Do While Worksheets("INSCRIPCIONES").Cells(PrimeraFila, 1) <> ""
        strNombre = Worksheets("INSCRIPCIONES").Cells(PrimeraFila, 4)
        strApellido = Worksheets("INSCRIPCIONES").Cells(PrimeraFila, 3)
        Set objSld = objPres.slides(1).Duplicate
        
        For Each objShp In objSld.Shapes
            If objShp.HasTextFrame Then
                If objShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    objShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace "<Nombre>", strNombre
                    objShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace "<Apellido>", strApellido
                    objShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace "<DNI>", strDNI
                End If
            End If
        Next
        PrimeraFila = PrimeraFila + 1
    Loop

    objPres.slides(1).Delete
    objPres.Save
End Sub ""
```

Comment: Bienvenid@ a la comunidad. No queda claro cuál es el error o cuál es el resultado esperado. Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega más detalles. Pásate por [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas la comunidad y las normas de publicación.

Comment: muchas gracias por responder. Lo que necesito que realice es leer una tabla de excel, y luego con los datos tomados de allí, me genere un archivo en pdf.  El inconveniente es que no corre, y por ello, no se po donde empezar.